# Handshake problem - 2016 participants

Tags: logic

I'm appealing to anyone who can give me a clear-cut, brief solution for this question. I'd like to just confirm my understanding of the correct approach to this problem...

*At a conference, the 2016 participants are registered from P1 to P2016. Each participant from P1 to P2015 shook hands with exactly the same number of participants as the one on their registration number. How many hands did the 2016th participant shake?*

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What do you think the correct approach is?

Comment: $1008$. Is this brief enough? But what are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: As an aside, a rephrasing of this problem appears in the book 'Problems for Mathematicians, young and old' by Halmos

Comment: Please re-title your question to 'A handshake problem'.. or something more meaningful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P_{2015}$ shook hands with everybody else, hence is the unique handshake-partner of $P_1$.
Then $P_{2014}$ shool hands with everybody else except one - which must be $P_1$; hence $P_{2014}$ and $P_{2015}$ are the handshake-partners of $P_2$.
This smells like induction.

**Claim.** Let $1\le n\le 1007$. Then $P_n$ shook hands precisely with $P_{2016-n},\ldots,P_{2015}$, and $P_{2016-n}$ shook hands with $P_n,\ldots,P_{2016}$ (except with themselves).

*Proof.* We have seen this above for $n=1$. Suppose $1<n\le 1007$ and the claim holds for all $k$ with $1\le k<n$.
Then from these smaller $k$, we know that $P_{2016-n}$ did not shake hands with the $n$ persons $P_1,\ldots, P_{n-1},$ and $P_{2016-n}$. Hence $P_{2016-n}$ must shake hands with everybody else, as desired.
Then $P_n$ shook hands with $P_{2016-k}$ for all $k< n$, but also with $P_{2016-n}$.
$\square$

By the same reasoning, $P_{1008}$ shook hands with $P_{1009},\ldots,P_{2016}$.
Finally, we learned along the way, who shakes hands with $P_{2016}$: $P_{1008},\ldots,P_{2015}$.

Answer (score 2):

Person $P2015$ will shake everybody elses hand, So person $P1$ cannot shake anybody elses hand.

Person $P2014$ will shake everbody (apart from $P1$), So $P2$ cannot shake anybody else.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\vdots 
\end{eqnarray*}

Person $P1008$ will shake everbody (apart from $P1,\cdots,P1006$), So $P1007$ cannot shake anybody else.

So $P2016$ will shake $\color{red}{1008}$ other peoples hands.